# How to get the Android API documentation in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, documentation, android

I'd like to be able to integrate Android api docs into Eclipse so that, for example, if hover over an `Activity` class you get the appropriate Javadoc in a popup.

So to add Javadoc to Android you open up any Android project in Eclipse. Location the "Android x.x" library. In this right click on the *android.jar* file and select Properties. Choose the Javadoc location entry.

In the JavadocURL section I entered http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html and clicked *Validate* but it gives the usual error of

*Location might be invalid. Files 'package-list' and 'index.html' that are typically available at the root of the documentation created by the Javadoc tool have not been found*

I've tried lots of variations of that URL but to no avail.

I also don't want to have to resort to downloading the source for Android.

Comment: Is there really no way to get the Android javadoc linked into Eclipse? I was sure I had it working a while ago before I needed to do a reinstall. Did Google use to ship the docs with the different versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BTW one possible (but unsatisfactory) solution is to get the Honeycomb API docs to access them offline. 
In the AVD Manager download the "Documentation for Android 'Honeycomb' Preview SDK" package. This installs into your .../android-sdk-linux_x86/ directory under docs. You can then link the `android.jar` file to it as detailed above.

I wouldn't mind being able to download the docs for the particular API version I use but I can't find it anywhere. I'd still prefer to access the online version.

Comment: Today (23 feb 11) Google released the documentation so that its no longer a preview. So this is the best way to add documentation locally since you can filter by API level also.

Comment: I have also noticed that now content assist takes an AGE to complete when you setup the above! I had to remove the setting. In fact to "remove" the setting you need to remove it an then click validate. Otherwise it seems to restore it. Total nuisance!

Comment: what is the benefit of filtering the http://developer.android.com/reference doc's by API level? If I filter by, say API level 7, does that show API's only available in API 7 and lower? I'm assuming this protects against targeting a certain version of android - and not using an API that isn't available, right?

Comment: Yes this is what filtering does. It stops you seeing methods which are not available for the version you are working against. Btw this question probably doesn't really belong in the comment section here. (as most people won't see it). You should post something like this as a separate question in future.

Answer (score 10):

In Eclipse right click the Android Library, and hit Configure Build Path. Then Select Android.jar and click Javadoc location. Click Edit then make sure Javadoc URL is selected. In the box, type in: "http://developer.android.com/reference/".

Comment: This works for me, though clicking "Validate" gives the above error "Location might be invalid...", which I guess can be ignored.